# Why is "libs" shown in red from libs.versions.toml used in build.gradle.kts files in android studio Giraffe?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, toml

I am using Android Studio Giraffe. In that new recommended way is to use Koltin build instead of groovy. So, when I created the new project, I got both Module and Project level build.gradle.kts files highlighted in red when I opened them with libs being highlited. There is seperate Version catalog file by name libs.version.toml

*Red highlight*

[image: build.gradle.kts]

> libs.versions.toml

```
[versions]
com-android-application = "8.1.0-alpha11"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.8.10"
core-ktx = "1.9.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
androidx-test-ext-junit = "1.1.5"
espresso-core = "3.5.1"
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = "2.6.1"
activity-compose = "1.7.0"
compose-bom = "2023.03.00"

[libraries]
core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "core-ktx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-test-ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-ext-junit" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espresso-core" }
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx" }
activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activity-compose" }
compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "compose-bom" }
ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }

[plugins]
com-android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "com-android-application" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }

[bundles]
```

> build.gradle.kts(Module)

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}
```

> build.gradle.kts(Project)

```
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}
```

I would also like to know more about libs.versions.toml file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `can't be called in this context by implicit receiver` message is [a known bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22797) in Gradle that was introduced when Version Catalogs were first added in Gradle 7.2.

[It will be fixed in Gradle 8.1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/23639), along with [some docs](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/23832) that will explain the workarounds for anyone using older versions of Gradle.

#### Workarounds

Until Gradle 8.1 is released, there are two workarounds.

The warning can be safely suppressed using `@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")`.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm)
}
```

Alternatively, there's an IntelliJ plugin that will suppress the error:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18949-gradle-libs-error-suppressor

Answer (score 2):

When I did Project Structure -> Project Gradle Version 8.4, the error was solved for me, try upgrading gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid compatibility issues, update your **AGP** to version 8.1.4 and your **Gradle to version** 8.4. Also, it is recommended that you use the latest version of Android Studio!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35314484)